# create empty copy of sql table and renaming both tables in a single operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table with many rows (5 milion rows per day).

I need to make processing of the data and i copy the data to a new table, it takes 20 minutes, and than truncates the main table.

can there be a way to create a new table that will replace the first table while the first table will be renamed so i can make additional processing on it?

Comment: exec sp_rename 'sourceTable', 'targetTable'

Comment: i think minimum three queries for copying, deleting and then renaming. At least you can make it a single transaction

Comment: What is the specific purpose of this needing to be done in "a single operation?"

Comment: Would it not be better to have an "archive" table and let an automated SQL job move data across to it every hour or so?  Or at midnight each night?  It seems unconventional to keep creating new tables.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a synonym or point to the correct table to solve you problem?  Use a stored procedure to update the pointer and do any cleanup like truncate table.

Problem:

**Switch table A with table B or vice verse.**

Solution:

1 - Have two empty tables TABLE_A and TABLE_B.

2 - Have a synonym that aliases TABLE_A as MY_DATA_TABLE.

3 - Load the data into the MY_DATA_TABLE.

4 - Have a procedure that truncates TABLE_B and recreates the synonym as TABLE_B.

Code has to be smart enough to choose next table, (A or B).

Code Sample - AUTOS database:

```
/*  
    Create the new database.
*/

-- Start with master database
USE MASTER;
GO

-- Delete existing databases.
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'AUTOS')
DROP DATABASE [AUTOS]
GO

-- Create a autos database
CREATE DATABASE AUTOS;
GO

-- Use the database
USE [AUTOS]
GO


/*  
    Create the new table A
*/

-- Remove table if it exists
IF  OBJECT_ID(N'[DBO].[BRAND_A]') > 0
DROP TABLE [DBO].[BRAND_A]
GO

-- Create a BRANDS table
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[BRAND_A]
(
MyId INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
MyValue VARCHAR(20)
)
GO


/*  
    Create the new Table B
*/

-- Remove table if it exists
IF  OBJECT_ID(N'[DBO].[BRAND_B]') > 0
DROP TABLE [DBO].[BRAND_B]
GO

-- Create a BRANDS table
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[BRAND_B]
(
MyId INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
MyValue VARCHAR(20)
)
GO


/*  
    Create base synonym
*/


-- Point to first table
CREATE SYNONYM [DBO].[BRANDS]
FOR [DBO].[BRAND_A]
GO


/*  
    Load data
*/

-- Load the brands table with data
INSERT INTO DBO.BRANDS (MyId, MyValue) VALUES
(1, 'Continental'),
(2, 'Edsel'),
(3, 'Lincoln'),
(4, 'Mercury'),
(5, 'Ram')
GO

-- Show me the data
SELECT * FROM DBO.BRANDS;
```

Code Sample - Switch the tables:

```
/*  
    Create Proc to roll synonym
*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [DBO].[SWITCH_TABLE]
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE @synonym_nm sysname;
    DECLARE @schema_nm sysname;
    DECLARE @object_nm sysname;
    DECLARE @sqlstmt nvarchar(512);

    -- Grab current definiton
    SELECT
        @synonym_nm = name, 
        @schema_nm = PARSENAME(base_object_name, 2), 
        @object_nm = 
            CASE 
            WHEN PARSENAME(base_object_name, 1) LIKE 'BRAND_A' THEN 'BRAND_B'
            WHEN PARSENAME(base_object_name, 1) LIKE 'BRAND_B' THEN 'BRAND_A'
            ELSE 'BRAND_A'
        END
    FROM sys.synonyms 
    WHERE name = 'BRANDS';

    -- Truncate opposite table
    SET @sqlstmt = 'TRUNCATE TABLE [' + @schema_nm + '].[' + @object_nm + '];';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstmt;
    --PRINT @sqlstmt;

    -- Drop synoymn
    SET @sqlstmt = 'DROP SYNONYM [DBO].[BRANDS];';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstmt;
    --PRINT @sqlstmt;

    -- Create synoymn
    SET @sqlstmt = 'CREATE SYNONYM [DBO].[BRANDS] FOR [' + @schema_nm + '].[' 
        + @object_nm + '];';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstmt;
    --PRINT @sqlstmt;

END

-- Switch the table
EXEC [DBO].[SWITCH_TABLE]
```